# Include both linear and non-linear dependency of the same variable in a multi-variate analysis

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation, predictor

I am implementing a multi-variate analysis using 5 covariates. My model looks like this:

```
lm1<-lm(Y ~ (T(A) +A + B + C + D + E)^2, data=data)
```

where T(A) is a transformation of A based on a exponential function.

I was wondering if it is statistically correct to include both the co-variate A and its transformation T(A) in the same model. I am also looking at interactions up to second order.

Anyone can give me some insights on it?

Comment: What is it that you want to know about interactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a variable and its transformation. The most common example would be a polynomial, where you add $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$, $\cdots$. You'll have to think carefully on how to interpret your model. You'll probably have to use graphs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also see that the interaction between A:T(A) have a strong impact on my model performance. Does that make sense to include the interaction between the two.?

Comment: It will add extra non-linearity to the effect of A. Whether or not that makes sense is something that only you can deside. Just plot your predictions and see if that function makes substantive sense. Additionally I would be careful if it adds a lot of non-linearity in areas where you have only a small number of observations or near the ends of the range of A. Moreover, what you are doing is a prety *ad hoc* approximation of a non-parametric model for the effect of A. Instead should probably be considering a more systematic non-parameteric model for A.

Comment: Alright. Thansk a lot.